# "';' is required" on first "=>" (vsc)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, discord.js

i got **';' required** error on first *=>* of this code

```
module.exports(client, aliases, callback) => {
    if(typeof aliases === "string" ){
        aliases = [aliases]
    }

    client.on("message", message => {
        const { content } = message;

        aliases.forEach(alias =>{
            const command = '${prefix}${alias}'

            if (content.startsWith('${command}') || content === command ){
                console.log("Running the command ${command}")
                callback(message)
            }
        })
    })

}
```

(the error shows up in => of this code;

```
module.exports(client, aliases, callback) =>
```

Comment: Is this supposed to export that function?

Comment: `module.exports(client, aliases, callback) => {` -> `module.exports.someNameHere = (client, aliases, callback) => {`

Comment: Or if you want to use a default export, `module.exports = ...`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you meant this:

```js
module.exports = (client, aliases, callback) => {
//...
}
```

I would guess the error is because `=>` is for defining functions, and what you did there, was trying to run a function. Then, the code found the `=>` unexpectedly since you didn’t declare a function, and threw the error.